# Javascript - Check if value exists in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a website with a simple Javascript login. And within this website, I want to check whether a username exists in the array. Although I am fairly new to the Javascript syntax, I still wanted to give it a shot, but I failed.
 Here's my failed attempt:

```js
// List of username's I want to block (aka. give error if they enter a username existing in this list)
var unAllowedUserNames = ["snapchat", "instagram", "youtube", "cocacola", "christoffer"]; /*5*/
// The username they enter
var username = document.getElementById("username");

// A simple function that alerts whether their username is valid or not
function validate() {
  // If username.value exists in unAllowedUserNames (index 1 though 4)
  if (username.value == unAllowedUserNames[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) {
    alert("Unallowed username!")
  } else {
    alert("Okay")
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" id="username"><br>

<input type="button" value="Register" onclick="validate()">
```

What I was "expecting" / what I want to achieve:
The `if (username.value == unAllowedUserNames[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) {` would iterate through the indexes defined in the square brackets (`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`), and return either true or false based on the results (results being, whether the username entered (`username.value`) was found in any of the indexes of the array)

I know that I can make a loop that iterates through all values in the array, and executes some code if the username matches any of the values. It *would* technically work, but it would be very inefficient and I bet there is a better function for it, and without using static values.

So is there any functions that can help me achieve my goal in a simple and fast matter?

Comment: That's not how you check if an array contains a value... use `Array#includes` or `Array#indexOf > -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check an array for element like that.

Try this:

```
function validate() {
  if (unAllowedUserNames.indexOf(username.value)>-1) {
    alert("Unallowed username!");
  } else {
    alert("Okay");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function validate() {
    if (unAllowedUserNames.indexOf(username.value) !== -1 ) {
        alert("Unallowed username!")
    } else if (unAllowedUserNames.indexOf(username.value) === -1) {
        alert("Okay")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you call `.indexOf()` twice to test the same value? Just a plain `else` without a condition is enough.

Comment: the original code used "if - else if" conditon, so I think there must be a reason for that. That's why I only changed the code so that it fix his "Array not working" problem